# Iterate through CSV up to a specific row

Tags: python-3.x

I have a current working script that iterates through rows in a CSV file currently, but I want to configure it to only read between a range, such as index 0 - 100, but am stuck on how to accomplish this properly.

Here is my current code:

```
for (name, subscriber) in zip(usernames, subscriber_ids):
 #do stuff with name / subscriber in selenium driver
    if len(elements) == 0:
        # logs information
    else:
        #logs information


with open('file', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    usernames = []
    subscriber_ids = []

    for row in readCSV:
        username = row[0]
        subscriberid = row[1]

        usernames.append(username)
        subscriber_ids.append(subscriberid)
```

What I want to do is just read from row 0 - 100 or start at index 100-200 etc. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Removed the Selenium tag since this question doesn't reference Selenium. I would suggest that you add tags around CSV or the CSV library you are using to get more targetted help.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
with open("datafile") as myfile:
head = [next(myfile) for x in range(N)]
print(head)
```

Comment: I kinda realized i should have expanded more, I actually want to run two scripts intandem but have them start at different indexes reading the csv. I.E One script will start reading at index [0:100] and the other at [101:200]